# Swashbuckle IExampleProvider showing array within array for List<T> parameter

Tags: asp.net-web-api, swagger, swashbuckle, swashbuckle.examples

I have a ASP.NET Framework (4.8) web API endpoint that accepts a parameter of type `List<T>` (simplifed method decoration with Swagger response/operation omitted for brevity):

```
[HttpPost]
[SwaggerRequestExample(typeof(CreateSiteDetails), typeof(CreateSiteExample))]
public HttpResponseMessage Site([FromBody] List<CreateSiteDetails> sitesToCreate)
{ ... }
```

The parameter and example classes are:

```
public class CreateSiteDetails
{
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(200)]
    public string SiteName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(500)]
    public string SiteDescription { get; set; }
}

public class CreateSiteExample : IExamplesProvider
{
    public object GetExamples()
    {
        return new List<CreateSiteDetails> {
            new CreateSiteDetails {
                SiteName = "London",
                SiteDescription = "..."
            },
            new CreateSiteDetails {
                SiteName = "Portsmouth",
                SiteDescription = "..."
            }
        };
    }
}
```

When viewing the automatically-generated Swagger documentation, it appears to generate an array within an array which isn't correct:

```
[
  [ // <-- Extra array being added
    {
      "SiteName": "London",
      "SiteDescription": "..."
    },
    {
      "SiteName": "Portsmouth",
      "SiteDescription": "..."
    }
  ]
]
```

Can anyone please offer an explanation of how to avoid this?  I tried to change the method attributes to this:

```
[SwaggerRequestExample(typeof(CreateSiteDetails), typeof(List<CreateSiteExample>))]
```

...but that threw an exception.  I've searched online and seen many other people struggling with arrays in other Swagger contexts, but nothing closely related to Swashbuckle.